# Record request execution flow in .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have been instructed to find all the file names through out the execution flow to complete a request.

Ex: suppose I have 4 project A(WEB), B, C, D, E

A is a web application and it's got a request to load home page. It's started executing the code, it's went to B then C then E then D for fetching data and it's came back to the calling function again where it had started. So I want to record all the project file names where my all execution happened.

though we can achieve same by debugging but looking for an easy way because my solution is too big.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the StackTrace is what you are looking for?

System.Environment.StackTrace

Sample: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/223611/how-to-log-the-current-call-stack-in-net